# How to get Video Play to pause slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, video, slider

I currently have a javascript slider in place. It's on autoplay at 5 seconds per slide. The second slide has an iframe youtube video.

Unfortunately, if I click play, 5 seconds later, the slider autplays to the next slide.

Is there any way to get the slider to recognize the video is playing, for example? Or are there any other ways around this that anyone can think of?

The JS code is simple, I'm using http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ for my slider.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery('#slider-1').cycle({
next: '#next-1',
prev: '#prev-1',
fx: 'fade',
timeout: 5000,
pause: 1,
pager: '#slider-nav-pager-1',
height: '433px',
width: '960px'
})
</script>
```

If you need more code, let me know. It's just a simple iframe.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use the [YouTube javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) if you want to know if the video is playing. Then you can listen to different events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using shadowbox-js to play the video so that the video can play while the slider continues operating in the background.